# How does Dockerfile ADD command work?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Trying to figure out how to use this command is frustrating. Apparently the files have to be inside the build context but now I've moved the file into the build context (or at least I think I have) and I'm still getting the same error:

```
INFO[0000] No source files were specified
```

Here's the directory structure on the host:

```
/srv/uwsgi/
       - Dockerfile
       - uwsgi.ini
```

Here's the pertaining commands of my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN sudo mkdir -p /srv/www/cc/
ADD ["./uwsgi.ini" "/srv/www/uwsgi.ini"]
```

Tried several variations on the ADD, with ./ and without, having the file outside of context and the full path.. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `ADD` files in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN sudo mkdir -p /srv/www/cc/
ADD ./uwsgi.ini /srv/www/uwsgi.ini
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer... so does the bracketed form not work any longer?

Comment: I have not seen brackets nor quotes work in ADD - btw, you probably want to use COPY instead of ADD.

Comment: is there a reason one should use ADD or COPY over the other? Reading the docs, they seem like exactly the same function.

Comment: http://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy - basically, COPY is more straight forward while ADD has some added "features"

Comment: This depends on the docker version. in 1.11 and 1.12 the the bracketed form works fine. Just make sure to use double quotes, not single.